# Torus as $\mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I can picture in my mind why a square with opposites sides "glued" is topologically equivalent to a torus. I cannot however picture what happens when we define the torus as $\mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$. Can anyone explain to me intuituvely what happens in this case? I think the notation $\mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$ means that if the difference between two pairs in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a pair of integers then they're equivalent. So in my mind instead of gluing opposites sides together what we do is like knitting the torus.

I guess I should construct some homeomorphism between the two spaces in order to prove that $\mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$ is a torus.

Comment: Take the square $[0,1]^2$ and note that any $(x,y)=(x-\lfloor x\rfloor,y-\lfloor y\rfloor)+(\lfloor x\rfloor,\lfloor y\rfloor),$ and the the second vector is in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and the first one is $[0,1]^2$. Thus, any class in $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ has a representative in $[0,1]^2$. Now apply the universal property of the quotient to build continuous maps from this.

Comment: Do you know how $[0,1]$ with the end points identified is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$? This is the same, only it happens in two dimensions at the same time. The dimensions don't really interact, thoguh, so you can think about them separately.